# Natural Deduction with Latex

Tags: logic

I am new to Latex and I would like to do natural deduction. I know there are many resources on internet and it has been mentioned here a lot too, but I have not been able to find a convenient, easy-to-use package or any other method for doing natural deduction with Latex. I want to have only vertical lines for my proofs (no horizontal lines) and add my own justifications, not a set of predefined justifications. To better illustrate my question, here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: Did you type "natural deduction" or "proof tree" in the search box at the top of this page and investigate the results of such a search?

Comment: Yes, the ones I found do not have the structure I am looking for.

Comment: Do you have a web link that explains this way of recording natural deductions in detail to give?

Comment: Unfortunately not. That is the way I learnt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This provides a sufficient start; setting the construction inside an `array` (with possible nesting):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\logicstep}{ o }{%
  \refstepcounter{enumi}(\theenumi)%
  \IfValueT{#1}{\ltx@label{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\logictitle}[1]{%
  \setcounter{enumi}{0}% Restart "logic" counter
  \makebox[.5\linewidth][l]{$#1$}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \logictitle{A / B \rightarrow A} \\[\jot]
    \begin{array}{c | l | l @{\qquad} l }
       \logicstep[first] & \multicolumn{3}{l}{A} \\
      \logicstep[second] & & B & \text{Supp $/~\rightarrow$ Int} \\
       \logicstep[third] & & A & \text{reit \eqref{first}} \\
              \logicstep & \multicolumn{1}{l}{B \rightarrow A} & & \text{$\rightarrow$ Int $\eqref{second} - \eqref{third}$}
    \end{array}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

`\logicstep[<label>]` sets the numbering in the first column. The optional `<label>` allows you to `\ref`erence it (using `\eqref` or otherwise).

---

Here's another visual:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\logicstep}{ o }{%
  \refstepcounter{enumi}(\theenumi)%
  \IfValueT{#1}{\ltx@label{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\logictitle}[1]{%
  \setcounter{enumi}{0}% Restart "logic" counter
  \makebox[.5\linewidth][l]{$#1$}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \logictitle{A / C \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)} \\[\jot]
    \begin{array}{c | l | l | l @{\qquad} l }
       \logicstep[first] & \multicolumn{3}{l}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\text{premise}} \\
      \logicstep[second] & \quad & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \text{Supp, $\rightarrow$ Int} \\
       \logicstep[third] &       &   & B                    & \text{Supp, $\rightarrow$ Int} \\
      \logicstep[fourth] &       &   & A                    & \text{Reit \eqref{first}} \\
       \logicstep[fifth] &       & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \text{$\rightarrow$ Int, \eqref{third}--\eqref{fourth}} \\
              \logicstep & \multicolumn{3}{l}{C \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)} & \text{$\rightarrow$ Int, \eqref{second}--\eqref{fifth}}
    \end{array}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

---

Now with a line-break:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\logicstep}{ o }{%
  \refstepcounter{enumi}(\theenumi)%
  \IfValueT{#1}{\ltx@label{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\logictitle}[1]{%
  \setcounter{enumi}{0}% Restart "logic" counter
  \makebox[.5\linewidth][l]{$#1$}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \logictitle{A / C \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)} \\[\jot]
    \begin{array}{c | l | l | l @{\qquad} l }
        \logicstep[first] & \multicolumn{3}{l}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\text{premise}} \\
       \logicstep[second] & \quad & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \text{Supp, $\rightarrow$ Int} \\
        \logicstep[third] &       &   & B                    & \text{Supp, $\rightarrow$ Int} \\
       \logicstep[fourth] &       &   & A                    & \text{Reit \eqref{first}} \\
                          &       \\[-.8\normalbaselineskip]
        \logicstep[fifth] &       &   & B                    & \text{Example 1} \\
        \logicstep[sixth] &       &   & A                    & \text{Example 2} \\
      \logicstep[seventh] &       & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \text{$\rightarrow$ Int, \eqref{third}--\eqref{fourth}} \\
               \logicstep & \multicolumn{3}{l}{C \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)} & \text{$\rightarrow$ Int, \eqref{second}--\eqref{fifth}}
    \end{array}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is more or less what I was looking for. I am wondering how would I be able to do more nested suppositions, say 3 for example. I could not figure it out.

Comment: @RobG.: I am completely unfamiliar with logical proofs and merely replicated the output. If you can provide a 3-supposition proof (through an image, say), I'm sure one can figure out how to nest these...

Comment: my apologies, I uploaded a new image with 3 suppositions. A proof like this can require even more suppositions at times.

Comment: @RobG.: See the end of my updated answer.

Comment: That works! I encountered another problem. Sorry, I did not see it coming first. How can I separate these vertical lines? I uploaded a new image. Also, when I compiled your code on my device, I saw the second vertical line appearing a little thicker than the other two. Do you know what might have caused the issue? Thanks

Comment: @RobG.: See the updated answer. With many modifications as you request, it might be easier to manage this using a graphics package like [`tikz`](//ctan.org/pkg/pgf) using a `matrix of nodes`.